# 'cordova run android --emulator' command line tool stuck at 'Waiting for emulator to start...'

Tags: cordova, android-studio, npm, command-line, adb

I've installed cordova and am using it to develop an android app. I have all the SDK tools installed.

I'm running into an issue where I cannot start the emulator form the command line. I see there are a lot of posts about this already, but none really answer the problem or show the verbose output from the command line tool.

Here is the command line output from the command

`cordova run android --emulator --verbose`

```
Waiting for emulator to start...
Running adb shell command "getprop dev.bootcomplete" on target emulator-5584...
Running command: adb -s emulator-5584 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
Command finished with error code 1: adb -s,emulator-5584,shell,getprop,dev.bootcomplete
Running adb shell command "getprop dev.bootcomplete" on target emulator-5584...
Running command: adb -s emulator-5584 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
Command finished with error code 1: adb -s,emulator-5584,shell,getprop,dev.bootcomplete
Running adb shell command "getprop dev.bootcomplete" on target emulator-5584...
Running command: adb -s emulator-5584 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
Command finished with error code 1: adb -s,emulator-5584,shell,getprop,dev.bootcomplete
```

And then it just keeps looping..

*Current workaround*

I have a workaround that just requires me to run the emulator from the Android Studio AVD Manager and then run

```
cordova emulate android
```

which runs the app on the emulator.

I'd like to get the command line tool working because it will speed up my productivity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This workaround was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks!